# Regular expression of json

Tags: json, regex

I had this part of json :
str =

```
"lien_images":
[
    "http://restaurant-greuze.secretbox.fr/sites/restaurant-greuze.secretbox.fr/files/imagecache/thumbnail_appi_ios/products/bp-greuze-facade-001[1].jpg",
    "http://restaurant-greuze.secretbox.fr/sites/restaurant-greuze.secretbox.fr/files/imagecache/thumbnail_appi_ios/products/bp-greuze-facade-001[0].jpg",
    "http://restaurant-greuze.secretbox.fr/sites/restaurant-greuze.secretbox.fr/files/imagecache/thumbnail_appi_ios/products/bp-greuze-facade-001[2].jpg"
],
"duree_de_validitee": "365"
```

I tried this  `String tab[] = str.split("lien_images\": [\",\\[\\]]+");`
But the result is not correct what I need is only link of images 
whithout the quotes or commas.

> http://restaurant-greuze.secretbox.fr/sites/restaurant-greuze.secretbox.fr/files/imagecache/thumbnail_appi_ios/products/bp-greuze-facade-001[1].jpg
>
> http://restaurant-greuze.secretbox.fr/sites/restaurant-greuze.secretbox.fr/files/imagecache/thumbnail_appi_ios/products/bp-greuze-facade-001[0].jpg
>
> http://restaurant-greuze.secretbox.fr/sites/restaurant-greuze.secretbox.fr/files/imagecache/thumbnail_appi_ios/products/bp-greuze-facade-001[2].jpg

I hope it's clear.

Comment: Why not use an actual JSON deserializer instead of reinventing the wheel? That way you'd get the actual values without any hassle.

Comment: How is the result not correct?  Why are you parsing this structure with a regular expression instead of just... accessing its fields directly?

Comment: because I need to put the links in image's downloader

Comment: Using a regex for this is generally a bad idea. You can probably get pretty close, and it could probably work reliably for you, but you're never going to get a spec-compliant regex for pulling those values from your JSON. It's just too complex. You really should parse your JSON and work with the object.

Comment: Also, where's the json? Can you post the actual data you're working with?

Comment: I m just a junior developer so my friends the company where I am, use this solution for a while even though it's a bad idea.
so, what I put is the result of parsed json so I must handle thos links and put it into an Arraylist<String>

Comment: Then, I presume it is C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys for being late, I'm in Africa so we had problems with internet 
this my solution, thank you.

```
  String tab[] = str.split("\"[\",\\[\\]]+");
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            if (!tab[i].isEmpty() && !tab[i].equals("[]") ) {
                //  tab[i] =  tab[i].replace("[]"," ");
                tab[i] = tab[i].replace("\\/","/");
                tab[i] = tab[i].replace("[\"","");
                tab[i] = tab[i].replace("\"]","");
                MyString myString = new MyString();
                myString.setMyString(tab[i]);
                list.add(myString);
            }
        }
```

the result is only links of images, for MyString it's a class to handle String.